# Postfix custom header based on externally defined alias category

Tags: postfix

On my mail server I have a bunch of aliases grouped into categories. The aliases are stored in a hash database with postmap.

```
aaa@domain foo-filter@domain
bbb@domain foo-filter@domain
ccc@domain bar-filter@domain
ddd@domain foo-filter@domain
...
foo-filter@domain mymailbox@domain
bar-filter@domain mymailbox@domain
...
```

My goal is to have automatic filtering built around the foo-filter and bar-filter addresses by adding a custom header. I created a header check:

```
/(.+filter)@domain/  PREPEND X-MyCustomFilter: $1
```

I added this to main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = (...) check_recipient_access pcre:/etc/postfix/addheader
```

When I sent mail to aaa@domain the header is not created, only when I sent mail directly to foo-filter@domain which defeats the purpose of using different addresses.

I would also be open to a solution using mysql lookups as the same data is also available in a mysql table.

Comment: I tried with mysql but first ran into problems that smtp runs in a chroot (can be turned off in master.cf) and then the recipient access restriction did not like the "mysql:" table prefix. Only got pcre: and regexp: tables to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a trivial/brute force solution. It's not what I expected, but maybe it is worthwhile enough to post here since I encountered a lot of little mishaps along the way.

**The solution: a hard-coded regex table**

Since I generate my alias file anyway I now simply generate a second file named `categories` that has a line for each alias that looks like this:

```
 /^aaa@domain/ PREPEND X-Category: foo
 /^bbb@domain/ PREPEND X-Category: foo
 /^ccc@domain/ PREPEND X-Category: bar
 /^ddd@domain/ PREPEND X-Category: bar
```

Just as an aside that first part between the `/` is a regex that matches the exakt address where `^` marks the start so I don't run into trouble with `aaa@domain` and `aaaa@domain`. (See more infos here: http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html)

From the documentation:

> Patterns are applied in the order as specified in the  table,  until  a
>          pattern is found that matches the input string.

This means that there is a caveat to this solution: hard-coding like this is *probably* not feasible for large servers. (Mine only serves two mailboxes)

**Other helpful things I found while debugging this:**

make sure the last line also as a linefeed, or else it will not be recognized. Then added this to main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = (...) check_recipient_access regexp:/path/to/categories
```

Reload postfix once. It does not need to reload when the categories file changes.

Very helpful command to check if everything works without sending 20k testmails goes like this:

```
postmap -q "aaa@domain" regexp:/path/to/categories
```

What is it all for: Now I can use sieve filters to check for that category. We use a lot of aliases and it makes it easy to set a category when creating the alias rather than having to go and added the new alias to sieve script.